# dovecot: I get the certificate on localhost, but not from outside

Tags: networking, ssl, certificate, dovecot

I had a dovecot/postfix/fail2ban setup running perfectly fine until some days ago: When I connect from outside (e.g. my localhost) I get

```
CONNECTED(000002F8)
write:errno=10054
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 326 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
Protocol  : TLSv1.2
Cipher    : 0000
Session-ID:
Session-ID-ctx:
Master-Key:
Key-Arg   : None
PSK identity: None
PSK identity hint: None
SRP username: None
Start Time: 1569483184
Timeout   : 300 (sec)
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

But when I connect locally

```
    me@example:/etc/dovecot/conf.d$ openssl s_client localhost:995
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = example.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = example.com
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
bla
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = example.com

issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-384, 384 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3274 bytes and written 767 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: bla
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Resumption PSK: bla
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    bla

    Start Time: 1569483321
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: bla
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Resumption PSK: bla
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    bla

    Start Time: 1569483321
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
+OK Dovecot (Ubuntu) ready.
```

I've searched through logs and didn't find anything suspicious. And, after all, it says clearly that I can connect on localhost and I get the certificate. Yet from outside I can connect (`CONNECTED(000002F8)`) but I don't get a certificate.

Where do I need to look..? What could potentially cause such an issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> write:errno=10054
>   ...
>   SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 326 bytes

While you can connect first the connection is then reset (10054 is WSAECONNRESET - Connection reset by peer). The possible cause of this is a  deep inspecting firewall somewhere between client and server which blocks the connection when it sees a TLS handshake and this protocol is not allowed. This results in no data read from the server (*"... has read 0 bytes"*) and thus also no certificate or any other server side part of the TLS handshake.

Comment: Oh, great, that's some fantastic info! Let me check and report back on the cause.

Comment: So, I disabled ufw, disabled fail2ban, and realized that another mail client (outlook.live.com) could successfully connect via imap. But locally, I get the connection reset both on 993 and 995. But I can log in per ssh, so it's probably not that my ip is banned...

Comment: @Doidel: *"... firewall somewhere __between__ client and server... "* - with between I mean neither on the client nor on the server but somewhere in between  - typically as a perimeter firewall in companies. Which also means that the other client might not be affected at all since it will come from another network (not from inside your company). Also, neither fail2ban nor ufw are **deep inspection** firewalls, i.e. these would block already the initial TCP connection and not decide based on the based on the payload when to block.

Comment: The issue was a cloudflare misconfiguration. (See e.g. https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168876-Email-undeliverable-when-using-Cloudflare#h.sf43uhyy1ztk)